# How can I find the segments that precede and follow a segment in a multiline

Tags: postgis, postgresql

[image]I have a multiline. Along it I have nodes which form intersections between the different segments of my multiline.

My goal is to inform each segment of the segment that precedes it and the segment that follows it in two columns of my multiline table.

I tried this query

```
select cm_code,
  (select cm_code from thd.t_cheminement n where st_intersects((p.geom), st_buffer(n.geom, 1))) cm1,
  (select cm_code from thd.t_cheminement n where st_intersects((p.geom), st_buffer(n.geom, 1))) cm2
from thd.t_cheminement p;
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Can you add a drawing to explain what your are trying to achieve? Or perhaps make a mock-up table of the expected output?

Comment: the drawing is added in the post as you can see. i just want to know for each segment which is the first neigbour and the following. tks

Comment: mmh...it's unlikely that you can add those colums to your 'multiline' table, as there is one (!) row per MULTILINESTRING, each (!) consisting of multiple individual LINESTRINGs (meaning that you would need to add two columns per (!) LINESTRING within each MULTILINESTRING)

Comment: ok! which function can i use do find the nearest (precede, following) of each linestring?

Comment: If you segmentize your MULTILINESTRINGs using ST_Dump, the nodes of the MULTILINESTRING will be duplicated to match the start/end nodes for each LINESTRING. You can then find connected LINESTRINGs by finding their respective nodes that equals (ST_Equals, ST_Intersects) either the start point (preceeding) or end point (following) of each LINESTRING. (sry I can't give you a query right now, no time)

Comment: Since yesterday i tried all queries but still not useful results. May someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will dump your MULTILINESTRINGs into LINESTRINGs with generated ids for each MULTILINESTRING (*multiline_id*) and their respective LINESTRING segments (*line_id*) and adds a colum for each LINESTRING's preceeding (*preceeding_id*) and following (*following_id*) LINESTRING.

It assumes that your LINESTRING segments are connected such that `ST_Intersects = TRUE` in case they have a neighbour. Also, it results in a new table, as inserting these (only) two columns in your '*multiline*' table doesn´t work.

This query is not optimized and might have overheads, but it should be easy to comprehend:

```
WITH

    linestrings AS      
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS line_id,
                sub_query.*
         FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS multiline_id,
                        (ST_Dump(geom)).geom
                 FROM   multiline)
         AS     sub_query),

    preceeding AS 
        (SELECT a.line_id   AS line_id,
                b.line_id   AS preceeding_id
         FROM   linestrings AS a,
                linestrings AS b
         WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_StartPoint(a.geom), b.geom)
           AND  a.line_id <> b.line_id),

    following AS    
        (SELECT a.line_id   AS line_id,
                b.line_id   AS following_id
         FROM   linestrings AS a,
                linestrings AS b
         WHERE  ST_Intersects(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), b.geom)
           AND  a.line_id <> b.line_id)

SELECT  ls.multiline_id,
        ls.line_id,
        p.preceeding_id,
        f.following_id
FROM    linestrings AS ls,
        preceeding  AS p,
        following   AS f
WHERE   ls.line_id = p.line_id
  AND   ls.line_id = f.line_id;
```